# jquery ajax loading gif

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do I add a loading gif during the jQuery AJAX processing? I read some tutorials, they use `beforeSend`. but still not see the loading thing.

```
<script src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
url: "index_2.php", 
dataType: "html",
type: 'POST', 
data: "value=something",
beforeSend: function () {
    $("#result").html('<img src="loding.gif" /> Now loding...');
},
success: function(data){ 
  $("#result").html(data); //even add .delay(5000)
}
});
</script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

index_2.php

```
<?php
sleep(5);
echo $_POST['value'];
?>
```

I set `sleep(5);` in `index_2.php`, it should show the `londing.gif` in the `div#result` for 5 seconds, until the data return from `index_2.php`.

Comment: Is it possible that you've got the name of the gif wrong? You specify `loding.gif` in the JS, then `londing.gif` in the question text, but presumably you mean `loading.gif`?

Comment: Are you seeing the result of the ajax request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be an idea is before calling the ajax request load the image like you done ie

```
$("#result").html('<img src="loding.gif" /> Now loding...');
```

then onsuccess bind the data

Comment: $(document).html('<img src="loding.gif" /> Now loding...'); will this work

Answer (score 2):

there's a couple of ways. My preferred way is to attach a function to the ajaxStart/Stop events on the element itself.

```
$('#loadingDiv')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;
```

The ajaxStart/Stop functions will fire whenever you do any ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `$.ajaxStart()` function, which will execute whenever any Ajax request is started (obviously).

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430438/how-to-call-jquery-ajaxstart-ajaxcomplete) for details.