# how to make two dependent ajax requests on one buttonclick

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want insert two forms as two table rows in db using a button click event.I have used ajax request to insert in database and done for one form, while making another ajax request depending on first form it is not working 
here is my java script using jquery.

```
var transportid = 2;
$.ajax({
    url : '/TransportJob/create',
    type : 'POST',
    data : $('form[action="/TransportJob/Create"]').serialize(),
    success : function sfn(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { // **success spelling mistake**
        transportid = parseInt(data);
        alert('inserted id :' + data);
        $('#TransportJobId').val((transportid));
        $.ajax({

            url : '/TransportJobAddress/create',
            type : 'POST',
            //beforeSend: function myintserver(xhr){
            //        $('#addAddress').html('<div id="temp_load" style="text-align:center">please wait ...</div>');
            //},
            data : $('form[action="/TransportJobAddress/Create"]').serialize(),
            success : function poste(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#addAddress').html(data);
            },
            error : function err(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error at address :' + errorThrown);
            }

        });
    },
    error : function myfunction(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error at transport :" + jqXHR.textStatus);
    },
    complete : function completefunc() {
        alert('ajax completed all requests');
    }

});
return false;
});
```

Comment: Any errors you re getting?

Comment: No I am getting only complete :event alert only .it is inserting in db for first form and second form not posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first ajax `sucess` spelling problem make correction `success` then it will work

Answer (score 0):

In your first ajax call, change`sucess` to `success` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have modify your code first ajax request success portion spelling mistake.

```
sucess : function sfn(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

Change to

```
success : function sfn(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

Second error at end of request is
Remove extra code

```
return false;
});
```

and Put `return false;` after closing `complete` method.
e.g.

```
    complete : function completefunc() {
        alert('ajax completed all requests');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I have changed as you said it improved more(before I am getting 2 times pop up), And one more help .When I use loading panel in above code (where i commented) it is always saying  at error function: internal server error

Comment: Can you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329261/jquery-ajax-loading-gif?rq=1