# "loading image" between start and end of a ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add a loading image that will be visible between the start and end of an ajax request in jquery.

Currently, when the button I want to replace with a loading image is clicked, this function is called:

```
function test(num)
{
             $("div.bd_img").attr("style", "display:none");
             $("div.ajax_load").attr("style", "display:block");
             str = "ajax?id=" + num.toString();

             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: str,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: test2
             });
             $("div.bd_img").attr("style", "display:block");
             $("div.ajax_load").attr("style", "display:none");

}
```

But it doesnt seem to be working.

The two divisions bd_img and ajax_load are childs of a div, so one should be replaced by another when display is set to none and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your test2 method.  I would also move your image switch into your success callback.

```
success: function() {
    $("div.bd_img").show();
    $("div.ajax_load").hide();

    test2();
}
```

check to make sure your div actually has the class bd_img and ajax_load and that class is not on the actual image.  right now you are saying that your div has the class '.bd_img' or '.ajax_load'.  if it is an image inside the div with the class, then you want ...

```
$("div .bd_img").show();
$("div .ajax_load").hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Disable the loader in the callback function (`test2` in your case)

[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) calls by definition are asynchronous.  Your current code will fire off the ajax GET and then carry straight on to disable your loader.  If you disable the loader in the callback from the ajax call you should see the behaviour you expect.

Comment: You mean just remove the succes: ... line? Tried that, didnt help :/.

Comment: @Tool: No, not at all.  `test2` is your callback function and therefore runs _after_ the ajax call has completed.  If you move the code to hide your loading image into that function, it'll work.  Basically, exactly what bdparrish said only his example uses an anonymous function to disable the loading image prior to calling `test2`.

Answer (score 1):

You should switch back the images inside `test2`. Ajax calls area asynchronous so `$.ajax(...)` returns immediately, not when the request is completed.

Ever wondered what the `A` of ajax stands for ? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [ajaxStart and ajaxStop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430438/how-to-call-jquery-ajaxstart-ajaxcomplete) This will make it work for your entire application, keep the code in one place, easy to be modified, etc.