# Possible to get percent complete of an ajax API request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a mobile app which has a number of API requests made via ajax.

I was wondering if there was a way to get a 'percent complete' figure that I could turn into a (accurate enough) loading bar.

My ajax calls look like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://WEBADDRESS&format=json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(results) {
    },
    error: function(results){
    }
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there progress update events in jQuery ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792558/are-there-progress-update-events-in-jquery-ajax)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157823/show-a-loading-bar-using-jquery-while-making-a-ajax-request -- I don't think it's possible to have an accurate loading bar only by using JS